# Tracing through a JSON string with dynamic (changing) array sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to navigate through a JSON array where the size of some objects may vary. The JSON snippet is too large to post, so I posted it on JSON Blob, **[HERE](https://jsonblob.com/547f0fb0e4b0cc17cdb27ad0)** and I am trying to go through this structure and grab the object with the highest value in one of its properties.

In the image below, I am trying to grab the "champion" object that has the highest number in "totalSessionsPlayed".

[image]

My problem is figuring out how to loop through, then capture the total session value, and then compare them and eventually retrieve the champion object with the highest total sessions. I am used to always hardcoding the values/pathway because it was always statically set in size, whereas with here the size can changes.

I believe I would need to something along the following...but I am not fully sure

```
json = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);

         $.each(json, function (i, el) {
                if (el.stats.totalSessionsPlayed > highestSession)
                {
                   highestSession = el.stats.totalSessionsPlayed...?
                }
          });
     //when done, somehow get the champion object that relates to that highestSession value.
```

I am still new to JSON and I am simply getting lost on traversing this dynamically-sized JSON.

Comment: What's the point of using `$.each` and `$.parseJSON` functions?

Comment: I had to end up using parseJSON as I have to securely call and use my API key within a C# controller, and when I return that JSON I believe its in a different "style" or something as compared to javascripts, so I have to parse the C# return JSON, into the javascript version. I made a post on it a few months ago and that was what worked from SO people. Looking at this, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ it seems that parsing it allows Javascript to actually interact with it, if the JSON is passed from another source, like my C# controller.

Comment: I understand that, the response is a string and you need to parse it into a JavaScript object. But Do you really need jQuery for that? There are JavaScript native functions: `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. The same about $.each - do you need it? You can just do `myArray.forEach(…)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create array to hold top champions (could be multiple if it is a tie)
2. Loop through the champions array
3. Use `>` to get the champion with highest `totalSessionsPlayed` value; and use `===` to determine whether there was already a different champion with same top score.
4. If it is a tie, add current champion to array, else create new array with new champion.

Solution code:

```
var highestSession = -1; // set it low initially
var topChamps = []; // array since could be a N-way tie
$.each(json.champions, function(idx, champion) {
  if (champion.id > 0 && champion.stats) {
    if (champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed > highestSession) {
      // new top score broke any possible ties
      topChamps = [champion]; // new array
      highestSession = champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed; // save new max value
    } else if (champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed === highestSession) {
      // it's a tie, add to list
      topChamps[topChamps.length] = champion;
    }
  }
});
```

Run this example snippet against the OP's actual JSON data:

```js
// fake json for example only
var json = {
  "summonerId": 22421317,
  "modifyDate": 1414692614000,
  "champions": [{
    "id": 110,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 5,
      "totalSessionsLost": 5,
      "totalSessionsWon": 0,
      "totalChampionKills": 32,
      "totalDamageDealt": 725106,
      "totalDamageTaken": 113405,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
      "totalMinionKills": 937,
      "totalDoubleKills": 3,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 52,
      "totalGoldEarned": 62141,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 6,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 613669,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 105253,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 55,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
      "maxNumDeaths": 14
    }
  }, {
    "id": 21,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 7,
      "totalSessionsLost": 1,
      "totalSessionsWon": 6,
      "totalChampionKills": 54,
      "totalDamageDealt": 1143509,
      "totalDamageTaken": 132528,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 18,
      "totalMinionKills": 1420,
      "totalDoubleKills": 7,
      "totalTripleKills": 1,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 56,
      "totalGoldEarned": 99924,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 24,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 973400,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 159071,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 67,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 18,
      "maxNumDeaths": 11
    }
  }, {
    "id": 19,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 18,
      "totalSessionsLost": 9,
      "totalSessionsWon": 9,
      "totalChampionKills": 94,
      "totalDamageDealt": 1864380,
      "totalDamageTaken": 764921,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 12,
      "totalMinionKills": 923,
      "totalDoubleKills": 3,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 154,
      "totalGoldEarned": 212650,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 14,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 932921,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 565418,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 241,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 12,
      "maxNumDeaths": 12
    }
  }, {
    "id": 89,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 41,
      "totalSessionsLost": 15,
      "totalSessionsWon": 26,
      "totalChampionKills": 162,
      "totalDamageDealt": 1655899,
      "totalDamageTaken": 1322562,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 12,
      "totalMinionKills": 1684,
      "totalDoubleKills": 6,
      "totalTripleKills": 1,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 318,
      "totalGoldEarned": 447598,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 16,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 434852,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 1042032,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 716,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 12,
      "maxNumDeaths": 14
    }
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
      "totalSessionsLost": 1,
      "totalSessionsWon": 0,
      "totalChampionKills": 14,
      "totalDamageDealt": 269323,
      "totalDamageTaken": 43294,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 14,
      "totalMinionKills": 91,
      "totalDoubleKills": 2,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 6,
      "totalGoldEarned": 18899,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 1,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 17923,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 236252,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 18,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 14,
      "maxNumDeaths": 6
    }
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 2,
      "totalSessionsLost": 1,
      "totalSessionsWon": 1,
      "totalChampionKills": 14,
      "totalDamageDealt": 229398,
      "totalDamageTaken": 50962,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
      "totalMinionKills": 250,
      "totalDoubleKills": 2,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 16,
      "totalGoldEarned": 22793,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 3,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 69735,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 157448,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 12,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
      "maxNumDeaths": 12
    }
  }, {
    "id": 114,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 2,
      "totalSessionsLost": 0,
      "totalSessionsWon": 2,
      "totalChampionKills": 10,
      "totalDamageDealt": 216804,
      "totalDamageTaken": 38006,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 6,
      "totalMinionKills": 334,
      "totalDoubleKills": 2,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 12,
      "totalGoldEarned": 20796,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 8,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 211956,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 2482,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 9,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 6,
      "maxNumDeaths": 9
    }
  }, {
    "id": 50,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
      "totalSessionsLost": 1,
      "totalSessionsWon": 0,
      "totalChampionKills": 7,
      "totalDamageDealt": 58537,
      "totalDamageTaken": 31729,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 7,
      "totalMinionKills": 62,
      "totalDoubleKills": 1,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 13,
      "totalGoldEarned": 8280,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 11119,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 46016,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 7,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 7,
      "maxNumDeaths": 13
    }
  }, {
    "id": 122,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
      "totalSessionsLost": 0,
      "totalSessionsWon": 1,
      "totalChampionKills": 5,
      "totalDamageDealt": 102450,
      "totalDamageTaken": 21890,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 5,
      "totalMinionKills": 142,
      "totalDoubleKills": 0,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 4,
      "totalGoldEarned": 11038,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 4,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 91836,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 7028,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 9,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 5,
      "maxNumDeaths": 4
    }
  }, {
    "id": 33,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 9,
      "totalSessionsLost": 5,
      "totalSessionsWon": 4,
      "totalChampionKills": 30,
      "totalDamageDealt": 808061,
      "totalDamageTaken": 240939,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 9,
      "totalMinionKills": 277,
      "totalDoubleKills": 3,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 53,
      "totalGoldEarned": 82246,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 2,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 263466,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 354351,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 95,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 9,
      "maxNumDeaths": 11
    }
  }, {
    "id": 80,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 13,
      "totalSessionsLost": 8,
      "totalSessionsWon": 5,
      "totalChampionKills": 91,
      "totalDamageDealt": 1471756,
      "totalDamageTaken": 309620,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
      "totalMinionKills": 1757,
      "totalDoubleKills": 10,
      "totalTripleKills": 1,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 125,
      "totalGoldEarned": 140885,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 24,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 1372131,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 84732,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 83,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
      "maxNumDeaths": 19
    }
  }, {
    "id": 63,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
      "totalSessionsLost": 0,
      "totalSessionsWon": 1,
      "totalChampionKills": 7,
      "totalDamageDealt": 84633,
      "totalDamageTaken": 10389,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 7,
      "totalMinionKills": 98,
      "totalDoubleKills": 1,
      "totalTripleKills": 0,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 2,
      "totalGoldEarned": 9926,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 16719,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 66391,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 6,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 7,
      "maxNumDeaths": 2
    }
  }, {
    "id": 32,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 17,
      "totalSessionsLost": 9,
      "totalSessionsWon": 8,
      "totalChampionKills": 100,
      "totalDamageDealt": 2324822,
      "totalDamageTaken": 511432,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
      "totalMinionKills": 830,
      "totalDoubleKills": 9,
      "totalTripleKills": 1,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 117,
      "totalGoldEarned": 194949,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 249779,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 1833229,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 208,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
      "maxNumDeaths": 10
    }
  }, {
    "id": 31,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 11,
      "totalSessionsLost": 6,
      "totalSessionsWon": 5,
      "totalChampionKills": 73,
      "totalDamageDealt": 1565889,
      "totalDamageTaken": 346947,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 16,
      "totalMinionKills": 667,
      "totalDoubleKills": 4,
      "totalTripleKills": 1,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 59,
      "totalGoldEarned": 122954,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 4,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 299979,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 940284,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 98,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 16,
      "maxNumDeaths": 8
    }
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "stats": {
      "totalSessionsPlayed": 129,
      "totalSessionsLost": 61,
      "totalSessionsWon": 68,
      "totalChampionKills": 693,
      "killingSpree": 285,
      "totalDamageDealt": 12520567,
      "totalDamageTaken": 3938624,
      "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 18,
      "totalMinionKills": 9472,
      "totalDoubleKills": 53,
      "totalTripleKills": 5,
      "totalQuadraKills": 0,
      "totalPentaKills": 0,
      "totalUnrealKills": 0,
      "totalDeathsPerSession": 987,
      "totalGoldEarned": 1455079,
      "mostSpellsCast": 0,
      "totalTurretsKilled": 106,
      "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 5559485,
      "totalMagicDamageDealt": 5599987,
      "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 3748,
      "totalFirstBlood": 0,
      "totalAssists": 1624,
      "totalHeal": 601627,
      "maxLargestKillingSpree": 9,
      "maxLargestCriticalStrike": 925,
      "maxChampionsKilled": 18,
      "maxNumDeaths": 19,
      "maxTimePlayed": 3633,
      "maxTimeSpentLiving": 1504,
      "normalGamesPlayed": 0,
      "rankedSoloGamesPlayed": 0,
      "rankedPremadeGamesPlayed": 0,
      "botGamesPlayed": 0
    }
  }]
}

var highestSession = -1; // set it low initially
var topChamps = []; // array since could be a N-way tie
$.each(json.champions, function(idx, champion) {
  if (champion.id > 0 && champion.stats) {
    if (champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed > highestSession) {
      // new top score broke any possible ties
      topChamps = [champion];
      highestSession = champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed; // save new max value
    } else if (champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed === highestSession) {
      // it's a tie, add to list
      topChamps[topChamps.length] = champion;
    }
  }
});

$(document.body).append("<div>TOP CHAMP ID(s): " + topChamps.map(function(champ) {
  return champ.id
}).join(", ") + "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the alert is still empty haha :(

Comment: I do return this from a c# controller will that matter at all? so my `json` is, $.ajax({
                url: "/PlayerLookUp/YourRankedData",
                type: "POST",
                data: "IDList=" + Y[i],
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp["json"] == "error") {
                        alert("no ranked data");
                    } else {
                        var tempInfo = "";
                        json = JSON && JSON.parse(resp) || $.parseJSON(resp);

Comment: it alerts(0), and thats it? Is there any way to just get one value too? A tie does not matter to me I will just use one of those as the top champ.

Comment: if you just want one result you can grab `topChamps[0]` instead.

Comment: I think that's working! one last request which I just now forgot, this can't count id: 0. id:0 means the players lifetime stats, not a champions, this why I kept getting champ 0 haha. P.S Thanks for bearing with me so far!!!

Comment: Nice.. yeah so just check `if (champion.id > 0)` before determining whether champion has max `totalSessionsPlayed` value

Comment: Instead of `topChamps=[]; topChamps[0]=champion;` it's better to simply do `topChamps=[champion];`. And you should use `topChamps.push(champion)` instead of `topChamps[topChamps.length]=champion;` for readability.

Comment: Moreover you shouldn't use loose comparison (`!=`), strict comparison ought to be used not to yield unexpected results (`!==`). I also think that checking against `null` is unnecessary here because the value can be `undefined` as well and the statement will fail. You probably wanted this instead: `champion.id && champion.stats && champion.stats.totalSessionsPlayed`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simply reduce the array. You don't need jQuery here at all because `forEach`, `map` and `reduce` are basic native operations built-in to Arrays in JavaScript.

```
var bestChamp = json.champions.reduce(function (prev, next) {
    if (prev.stats.totalSessionsPlayed >= next.stats.totalSessionsPlayed) {
        return prev;
    } else {
        return next;
    }
});

// bestChamp contains the object
```

`reduce` transforms an array into a single value/object. So in this case we transform the array of `champions` into one object, with the highest number of `totalSessionsPlayed`.

You can read more about [`Array.prototype.reduce` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

If you additionally want to exclude objects with `id = 0` then it's as simple as adding this condition to the `if`-statement:

```
var bestChamp = json.champions.reduce(function (prev, next) {
    if (next.id === 0) {
        return prev;
    }

    if (prev.stats.totalSessionsPlayed >= next.stats.totalSessionsPlayed) {
        return prev;
    } else {
        return next;
    }
});

// bestChamp contains the object
```

Here's the whole snippet:

```js
var json = {
  "summonerId": 22421317,
  "modifyDate": 1414692614000,
  "champions": [
    {
      "id": 110,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 5,
        "totalSessionsLost": 5,
        "totalSessionsWon": 0,
        "totalChampionKills": 32,
        "totalDamageDealt": 725106,
        "totalDamageTaken": 113405,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
        "totalMinionKills": 937,
        "totalDoubleKills": 3,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 52,
        "totalGoldEarned": 62141,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 6,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 613669,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 105253,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 55,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
        "maxNumDeaths": 14
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 7,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 6,
        "totalChampionKills": 54,
        "totalDamageDealt": 1143509,
        "totalDamageTaken": 132528,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 18,
        "totalMinionKills": 1420,
        "totalDoubleKills": 7,
        "totalTripleKills": 1,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 56,
        "totalGoldEarned": 99924,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 24,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 973400,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 159071,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 67,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 18,
        "maxNumDeaths": 11
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 18,
        "totalSessionsLost": 9,
        "totalSessionsWon": 9,
        "totalChampionKills": 94,
        "totalDamageDealt": 1864380,
        "totalDamageTaken": 764921,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 12,
        "totalMinionKills": 923,
        "totalDoubleKills": 3,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 154,
        "totalGoldEarned": 212650,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 14,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 932921,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 565418,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 241,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 12,
        "maxNumDeaths": 12
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 89,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 41,
        "totalSessionsLost": 15,
        "totalSessionsWon": 26,
        "totalChampionKills": 162,
        "totalDamageDealt": 1655899,
        "totalDamageTaken": 1322562,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 12,
        "totalMinionKills": 1684,
        "totalDoubleKills": 6,
        "totalTripleKills": 1,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 318,
        "totalGoldEarned": 447598,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 16,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 434852,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 1042032,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 716,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 12,
        "maxNumDeaths": 14
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 0,
        "totalChampionKills": 14,
        "totalDamageDealt": 269323,
        "totalDamageTaken": 43294,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 14,
        "totalMinionKills": 91,
        "totalDoubleKills": 2,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 6,
        "totalGoldEarned": 18899,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 1,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 17923,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 236252,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 18,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 14,
        "maxNumDeaths": 6
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 2,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 1,
        "totalChampionKills": 14,
        "totalDamageDealt": 229398,
        "totalDamageTaken": 50962,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
        "totalMinionKills": 250,
        "totalDoubleKills": 2,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 16,
        "totalGoldEarned": 22793,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 3,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 69735,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 157448,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 12,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
        "maxNumDeaths": 12
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 114,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 2,
        "totalSessionsLost": 0,
        "totalSessionsWon": 2,
        "totalChampionKills": 10,
        "totalDamageDealt": 216804,
        "totalDamageTaken": 38006,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 6,
        "totalMinionKills": 334,
        "totalDoubleKills": 2,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 12,
        "totalGoldEarned": 20796,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 8,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 211956,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 2482,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 9,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 6,
        "maxNumDeaths": 9
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 0,
        "totalChampionKills": 7,
        "totalDamageDealt": 58537,
        "totalDamageTaken": 31729,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 7,
        "totalMinionKills": 62,
        "totalDoubleKills": 1,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 13,
        "totalGoldEarned": 8280,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 11119,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 46016,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 7,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 7,
        "maxNumDeaths": 13
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 122,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalSessionsLost": 0,
        "totalSessionsWon": 1,
        "totalChampionKills": 5,
        "totalDamageDealt": 102450,
        "totalDamageTaken": 21890,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 5,
        "totalMinionKills": 142,
        "totalDoubleKills": 0,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 4,
        "totalGoldEarned": 11038,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 4,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 91836,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 7028,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 9,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 5,
        "maxNumDeaths": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 33,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 9,
        "totalSessionsLost": 5,
        "totalSessionsWon": 4,
        "totalChampionKills": 30,
        "totalDamageDealt": 808061,
        "totalDamageTaken": 240939,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 9,
        "totalMinionKills": 277,
        "totalDoubleKills": 3,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 53,
        "totalGoldEarned": 82246,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 2,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 263466,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 354351,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 95,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 9,
        "maxNumDeaths": 11
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 80,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 13,
        "totalSessionsLost": 8,
        "totalSessionsWon": 5,
        "totalChampionKills": 91,
        "totalDamageDealt": 1471756,
        "totalDamageTaken": 309620,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
        "totalMinionKills": 1757,
        "totalDoubleKills": 10,
        "totalTripleKills": 1,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 125,
        "totalGoldEarned": 140885,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 24,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 1372131,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 84732,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 83,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
        "maxNumDeaths": 19
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 63,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalSessionsLost": 0,
        "totalSessionsWon": 1,
        "totalChampionKills": 7,
        "totalDamageDealt": 84633,
        "totalDamageTaken": 10389,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 7,
        "totalMinionKills": 98,
        "totalDoubleKills": 1,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 2,
        "totalGoldEarned": 9926,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 16719,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 66391,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 6,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 7,
        "maxNumDeaths": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 32,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 17,
        "totalSessionsLost": 9,
        "totalSessionsWon": 8,
        "totalChampionKills": 100,
        "totalDamageDealt": 2324822,
        "totalDamageTaken": 511432,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 13,
        "totalMinionKills": 830,
        "totalDoubleKills": 9,
        "totalTripleKills": 1,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 117,
        "totalGoldEarned": 194949,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 249779,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 1833229,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 208,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 13,
        "maxNumDeaths": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 11,
        "totalSessionsLost": 6,
        "totalSessionsWon": 5,
        "totalChampionKills": 73,
        "totalDamageDealt": 1565889,
        "totalDamageTaken": 346947,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 16,
        "totalMinionKills": 667,
        "totalDoubleKills": 4,
        "totalTripleKills": 1,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 59,
        "totalGoldEarned": 122954,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 4,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 299979,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 940284,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 98,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 16,
        "maxNumDeaths": 8
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 0,
      "stats": {
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 129,
        "totalSessionsLost": 61,
        "totalSessionsWon": 68,
        "totalChampionKills": 693,
        "killingSpree": 285,
        "totalDamageDealt": 12520567,
        "totalDamageTaken": 3938624,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 18,
        "totalMinionKills": 9472,
        "totalDoubleKills": 53,
        "totalTripleKills": 5,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 987,
        "totalGoldEarned": 1455079,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 106,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 5559485,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 5599987,
        "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 3748,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalAssists": 1624,
        "totalHeal": 601627,
        "maxLargestKillingSpree": 9,
        "maxLargestCriticalStrike": 925,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 18,
        "maxNumDeaths": 19,
        "maxTimePlayed": 3633,
        "maxTimeSpentLiving": 1504,
        "normalGamesPlayed": 0,
        "rankedSoloGamesPlayed": 0,
        "rankedPremadeGamesPlayed": 0,
        "botGamesPlayed": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}

var bestChamp = json.champions.reduce(function (prev, next) {
    if (next.id === 0) {
        return prev;
    }

    if (prev.stats.totalSessionsPlayed >= next.stats.totalSessionsPlayed) {
        return prev;
    } else {
        return next;
    }
});

alert(bestChamp.id);
```

Comment: Nice tip about `reduce`. This is definitely more concise than my solution (the accepted answer), but this doesn't mean you need to post rude comments. Also, your solution fails to handle ties for `totalSessionsPlayed`, hence downvote.

Comment: OP said he doesn't care about ties and wants just a single object @nothingisnecessary

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something simpler, you might consider this:

```
json.champions.reduce(function(current, champ) {
    return champ.stats.totalSessionsPlayed > current.stats.totalSessionsPlayed
            ? champ : current;
});
```

It doesn't have the error-checking in the answer from @nothingisnecessary, nor does it allow for the possibility of ties, just choosing the first one with the highest total.  But it's very simple code.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that this is essentially the same as Miszy's code.  I saw all the code in that answer and figured it was something different.  :-(  There are minor differences.  Mine returns the _first_ one with the maximum.  That one returns the _last_ one.  And that one does the error-checking on the data.  But the essence is the same.

Comment: This is a working answer and it's a little bit different than mine.

Comment: That's why I didn't just delete it when I realized.